# Optimization methods used from scipy.optimize to nlopt package

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, nlopt, objective-function

I am currently having a black box of objective function. It has been use successfully in `scipy.optimize` as 'status=op.basinhopping(obj,sp,...)', however, when I try the same obj to NLOPT package, it gives a message of

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given).
```

I suppose obj for `scipy.optimize` has two arguments, one is the function itself and the other is differentiation of each dimension, while obj used in NLOPT methods only require the function itself. If I am right about it, how should I modify the obj so that it could be used in NLOPT?
My code of using NLOPT

```
    sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"build/R_ulp"))
    import foo as foo_square
    reload(foo_square)
    sp=np.zeros(foo_square.dim)+args.startPoint
    obj=lambda X:foo_square.R(* X)
    opt = nlopt.opt(nlopt.GN_CRS2_LM, foo_square.dim)
    opt.set_min_objective(obj)
    opt.set_lower_bounds(-1e9)
    opt.set_upper_bounds(1e9)
    opt.set_stopval(0)
    opt.set_xtol_rel(1e-9)
    opt.set_initial_step(1)
    opt.set_population(0)
    opt.set_maxeval(100000) 
    status = opt.optimize([0.111111111]*foo_square.dim)
```

Comment: could you include all your code?

Comment: It looks like `opt.set_min_objective()` should be `opt.set_min_objective(obj)`.  I assume that is just a mistake made when the code was put in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SciPy optimizers and NLopt have different conventions for the signature of the objective function.  The [documentation for the objective function in NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Python_Reference/#objective-function) says

> The function `f` should be of the form:
>
> ```
> def f(x, grad):
>    if grad.size > 0:
> ```

etc.

So you'll need to create an objective function that accepts two arguments, `x` and `grad`.  If `grad.size > 0`, the function must fill in the array with the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider `functools.partial`, if your objective needs additional parameters:

Example: Instead of

```
obj = lambda x, grad, y1: foo_square.R(x, y=y1)
```

... you might use:

```
from functools import partial
[...]
obj = partial(foo_square.R, y=y1)
```

`obj` will also be accepted by NlOpt, as now the function signature matches again.